# Visual Studio "Open File" dialog: how do I change the default file extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, I click on "Open File" (ctrl+O), but by default, the dialog box in the in the lower-right corner that tells VS which extensions to look for always says `"Unit Test Files (*.cpp; *.h)"`, and I have to click on it and select `"All Files (*.*)"` to get it to display files that aren't .cpp or .h files. How can I change the default from  "Unit Test Files" to "All Files"? I was unable to find any official documentation about this from Microsoft, but in previous versions of VS (e.g. VS2017) "All Files" was the default, so I assume it can be changed somehow

Comment: Maybe that is because you are in the Test Project and not in a the regular project?

Comment: @Hugo no, it doesn't matter which project I'm in, the behavior is the same

Comment: It remembers the previous selection.  So to go back, you'll need to select "All Files" once and that now becomes the default.